# Refresh/Recalculate rollup field automatically using plugin in d365

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have a rollup field called "invoice total" in the Invoice(parent) entity which calculates the amount of "invoice qty" available in the Invoice detail(child) entity.
The rollup field should be recalculated/updated based on invoice detail creation, update and deletion without waiting for the system job to run.

I wrote the below plugin code to generate the logic but it doesn't trigger. I'm new to plugin.

```cs
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

Entity invoiceDetail = null;

try
{
    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        invoiceDetail = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

    var invoiceDetailId = invoiceDetail.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_invoice").Id;

    CalculateRollupFieldRequest request = new CalculateRollupFieldRequest
    {
        Target = new EntityReference("new_invoice", invoiceDetailId),
        FieldName = "new_invoicettotal"
    };

    CalculateRollupFieldResponse response = (CalculateRollupFieldResponse)service.Execute(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Did you register any plugin step?

Comment: yes. I registered on post operation synchronous on create of invoice detail

Comment: Did you try registering for update and delete also? Did you check the plugin trace log?

Comment: No. I tried with create only.I added traces after invoiceDetailId that is cpming

Comment: So there’s some exception ?

Comment: on create of Invoice detail record this code is perfectly working now. But when updating the "invoice qty" it is not working getting an object reference not set to an instance issue

Comment: please make sure you understand what is contained inside the context of the execution. An update message will only include those fields that changed, if you try to retrieve a value for something that did not update, your plugin won't find it, giving you that error.

Comment: I have successfully used [Andrew Butenko's Ultimate Workflow Toolkit](https://github.com/AndrewButenko/UltimateWorkflowToolkit/releases/tag/v1.3.0.0) to trigger rollup recalculation of rollup fields on the Invoice.